# First-order derivatives of the flow of a second-order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I find the first-order derivatives of a solution $\varphi(t,t_0, x_0, x_0', \lambda)$ of the ode

$$
    x'' = f(t,x,x',\lambda),  \quad x(t_0) = x_0,  \quad x'(t_0) = x'_0 \ ?  
$$

UPDATE: For the time derivative $\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial t}$, I started by defining $y(t, t_0, x_0, x'_0, \lambda) = \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial t} (t, t_0, x_0, x'_0, \lambda)$, and then such $y$ satisfies a first-order ODE:

$$
   \frac{\partial y}{\partial t} = \int_{t_0}^t
 f(s, \varphi(s, t_0, x_0, x'_0, \lambda), \lambda) ds
$$

with initial condition $y(t_0, t_0, x_0, x'_0, \lambda) = x'_0$, so by the integral formula for the solution of an ODE, it comes that:

$$
   \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial t} (t, t_0, x_0, x'_0, \lambda) = \varphi(t_0, t_0, x_0, x'_0, \lambda) +\int_{t_0}^{t} \int_{t_0}^{s}
 f(u, \varphi(u, t_0, x_0, x'_0, \lambda), \lambda)du ds \ .$$
 It seems right for me, but can I find similar formulas for the derivatives in $x$ and $\lambda$?

Comment: In which variable do you want to differentiate?

Comment: All of them. For the time derivative, I came to something like putting $y(t, t_0, x_0, x'_0, \lambda) = \partial \varphi(t, t_0, x_0, x'_0, \lambda)/\partial t$ etc, and showing that $y$ satisfies an ODE with initial condition $x'_0$. then a formula for $y$ comes from the integral formula for the solution of an ODE. I don't know about the others, though.

Comment: Something similar works. I like the treatment of the book by Perko, let me find the link

Comment: Have a look at Theorem 1, Section 2 of this book, I think it is what you are looking for:  https://books.google.es/books?id=A7fvvz9Puf8C&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false (unfortunately the theorem is not in the preview)